# User input blocks drawing in JAVA

Tags: java, draw

I am newbie in java. I have a following program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class UserInterfaceTriangle {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int x0;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter x coordinate of first point: ");
    //x0 = keyboard.nextInt();

    Points p1= new Points(5,3);

    Points p2= new Points(6,6);
    Points p3= new Points(2,-2);

    Triangle n1= new Triangle (p1,p2,p3);

    n1.DrawTriangle();



}
```

}

If I uncomment following , program does not draw triangle.

```
x0 = keyboard.nextInt()
```

But works fine as it is pasted above.

Comment: Did you enter something ?

Comment: That's because the Scanner is waiting for your input.  Try typing a number into the console and pressing enter.

Comment: Like your title says, `.nextInt()` blocks the program until you enter some input.

Comment: I do enter the a number, but still it does not draw triangle. It blocks

Comment: Don't mix console and GUI approaches

Comment: So then how do I take input from user and draw accordingly